# Why calling class function from a thread works in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, thread-safety, instance

So I got this weird scenario that works fine but doesn't make any sense as to why it works. From my experience in C++, I'm very sure that this will not work at all and will throw an error during compilation.

```
public class Practice {

    private void testFunction() {
        System.out.println("working fine");
        System.out.println("testFunc: " + this);
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("start: " + this);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("run: " + this);
                testFunction();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

// Inside main
Practice practice = new Practice();
practice.start()
```

Output

```
start: com.company.Practice@5e2de80c
run: com.company.Practice$1@6720b744
working fine
testFunc: com.company.Practice@5e2de80c
```

WHY!? why did this work? How am I able to call `testFunction()` from a Runnable? Shouldn't I create a new instance and then call that function like `Practice p = new Practice(); p.testFunction()`? How does Java know that `testFunction()` is part of `Practice` class and not `Runnable`?

And also, how come the value of `this` in `testFunction()` is same as `start()`? Shouldn't it be same as `run()`?

Comment: In your code `new Runnable(){..}` is being declared as anonymous class. These classes have access to enclosing class members. Refer this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `testFunction` is because you are using the *simple name* of `testFunction`. If instead you did:

```
this.testFunction();
```

Then you wouldn't be able to access it.

When you call a method with its simple name, everything that is in scope is considered to resolve the method. (See [JLS 6.5.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.7.1)) `testFunction` is definitely in scope inside the `Runnable`, because it is inside `Practice`.

To call `testFunction`, you still need an instance of `Practice`, right? Well, the compiler generates some code that passes the instance of `Practice` on which `start` is invoked (i.e. what `this` means in `start`) to the instance of `Runnable` that you are creating. Specifically, it creates a non-static inner class

```
class Practice {
    public void start() {
        ...
        new Thread(new SomeGeneratedRunnable()).start();
    }
    // not the actual name of the class. The actual name is Practice$1
    private class SomeGeneratedRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("run: " + this);
            testFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

You can think of this as:

```
class Practice {
    public void start() {
        ...
        new Thread(new SomeGeneratedRunnable(this)).start();
    }
}

class SomeGeneratedRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Practice outer;

    public SomeGeneratedRunnable(Practice outer) {
        this.outer = outer;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run: " + this);
        outer.testFunction();
    }
}
```

Now you should see why `this` inside `testFunction` can't possibly be the same as the `this` inside the `Runnable`. The `this` inside `Runnable` is an instance of `SomeGeneratedRunnable` (or `Practice$1`), but `this` inside `testFunction` is an instance of `Practice`.

Comment: Note: it should also work with `Practice.this.testFunction()` (`Practice.this` is a reference to the instance of `Practice`)

Answer (score 2):

You have an "inner class" here.

Instances of the inner class (your anonymous subclass of Runnable) will contain references to the containing outer classes they were created from (here an instance of Practice) and can call methods on those outer instances.

Your `testFunction();` gets compiled to something like `this.$myOuterInstance.testFunction();`

> How does Java know that testFunction() is part of Practice class and not Runnable?

The compiler resolves this by first looking at the inner class then going to the outside scope, which not only includes the containing class, but for example also any effectively final local variables you might have in that `start` method.

This is similar to how variables and fields are resolved as well (with some shadowing rules when you have name conflicts).

> And also, how come the value of this in `testFunction()` is same as `start()`? Shouldn't it be same as `run()`?

No. `testFunction` is invoked on the instance of `Practice` (as is `start`).

`run` is invoked on the instance of your Runnable `Practice$1`.

Comment: Nice explanation! Thanks!